# Password entropy logarithm

Tags: authentication, passwords, entropy

I've a password with a length of 10 and 78 unique characters. I know that the first two characters of the password must be digits (from 0-9). My calculation is:

```
E = log2(10^2) + log2(78^8) = 56,93
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is the correct calculation for information-theoretic entropy.

Remember though, entropy is a measure of the uncertainty generated by a source, not a property of the generated bits themselves.